# In Python, how can I compare a numpy array to each row of a matrix to chose the row that is most similar to the vector?

Tags: python, numpy

For instance, if I have a 1D array `[91, 119, 161, 203, 259]` and a 2D array `[[90,120,160,200,260], [95,115,165,204,255]]`, how can I determine which row from the latter is a better match for the former?

In this case, it would be the first row because most numbers are only off by 1, whereas in the second row most numbers are off by 4. Also, the RMSE between the vector and the first row is 1.612, whereas for the second row it is 3.606.

Comment: What do you mean by "vector" and "matrix"? How are you storing your data?

Comment: What have you tried? It seems you already pretty much know how you'd do it by hand (per your second paragraph), try writing it out as code?

Comment: @gmds By "vector" I mean a single array or list of numbers. By "matrix" I mean an array of arrays or list of lists. Please feel free to edit or tell me how best to improve the language.

Comment: "array" has a specific meaning in Python *distinct* from "list". A list is a native Python object, whereas "array" can refer to either a `numpy` array (far more common) or the `array` package in the standard library. Which one you mean will affect the solution.

Comment: @sabik So far I only have ugly broken code for this. Also, this is actually a simplification of my larger problem. I need to create a matrix with 10,000 rows for which each row is essentially a ruler with different sized increments. Then I need to test each ruler to see how well it fits the vector of data I have. Vectors vary in length.

Comment: @gmds I see, thanks for the clarification. I'm coming from R so this is new to me. I'm currently using numpy to create an array, but I think I could achieve my goal by using a list. I'm not sure what the limitations of either are.

Comment: In general, for numeric computation you want to use `numpy` arrays because they are a more convenient abstraction, supporting, for example, elementwise operations. However, I would say your question is too wide right now, because you're asking a statistical question (what the best method to determine the distance between vectors is), and a programming question (how to implement that).

Comment: @gmds Good point, I suppose I am asking two questions in one. I'll keep that in mind for future questions I post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many distance metrics, but cosine is a good measure for vector similarities. You can use `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine` to find the cosine distance. You'll want the vector with the smallest cosine distance.

In code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

v = np.array([91, 119, 161, 203, 259])
matrix = np.array([[90,120,160,200,260], [95,115,165,204,255]])
assert np.argmin([cosine(v, row) for row in matrix]) == 0
```

Comment: Thank you, this is an interesting suggestion that I think will work. How can I write the code so that after it measures all of the cosine distances, it returns the row with the lowest distance value?

Comment: It's already doing that. `np.argmin` means "find the row number corresponding to the smallest distance"

Comment: I see, so when it returns "True" it is saying row 0 is the lowest. But suppose I had more than two rows and it had returned "False"?

Comment: It is not returning `True`. I'm demonstrating that the smallest row is row 0 by asserting that `np.argmin` returns 0 (the index of the argument with the smallest distance).

Comment: Great, I get it now. Just had to remove == 0.